# Ban DM Message on discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot, and I want the bot to DM the user that got banned why 
it got banned. Here is my current code for it:

```
    if(command === "ban") {
  if(!message.member.roles.some(r=>["Administrator"].includes(r.name)) )
return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to use this!");

let member = message.mentions.members.first();
if(!member)
  return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server");
if(!member.bannable) 
  return message.reply("I cannot ban this user! Do they have a higher role? 
Do I have ban permissions?");

let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
if(!reason) reason = "No reason provided";

await member.ban(reason)
  .catch(error => message.reply(`Sorry ${message.author} I couldn't ban because of : ${error}`));
message.reply(`${member.user.tag} has been banned by ${message.author.tag} because: ${reason}`);
  message.member.tag.sendMessage('Hi! You were banned from ${member.user.server} because: {reason}. If you do not get why you were banned, please DM @doodthedoodthedood#2695.')
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant send the message to the user because you banned them, meaning you no longer share a server.
*Send the message first.*
`.send` is a promise. use it to your advantage.

```
message.member.send(`ban reason here`).then(function(){
    message.member.ban(`reason`)
    console.log(`Successfully sent ban message to ${message.member.tag}`);
}).catch(function(){
   message.member.ban(`reason`)
   console.log(`Unsuccessfully sent ban message to ${message.member.tag}`);
});
```

use `.then` and a `.catch` to ban the user so even if the message doesnt send they still get banned

Answer (score 2):

**You would have to do it before they are banned.**

Before banning the user, use the member object to send them a message.

```
await member.send("You are banned")
await member.ban(reason)
```

Comment: It did not work. I put it on, but it did not send a dm.

Comment: Are DMS (not from friends) enabled for the user? Also, is there an error?

Comment: @TylerSilberman Can the bot *actually* DM the person, and do you have an error that would explain it. A forbidden error usually means the bot cannot DM the person