# Send a private message to the person you want to kick (discordjs)

Tags: discord.js, bots

I'm coming to you because I'm stuck on a slight problem. Being in the process of creating a kick command for my Discord bot I would like that before being kicked the person receives a DM from the bot which tells him that he was kicked from such server by such person and especially why. But I don't really know how to do it or where to put the code in my command code. thanks >I'm a beginner in JS

```
module.exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
const reason = (args.splice(1).join(' ') || 'Aucune raison spécifiée');
user ? message.guild.member(user).kick(reason) : message.channel.send("L'utilisateur n'existe pas !");
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Just paste A SHORT REPRODUCEABLE SAMPLE of it, consider reading the Stackoverflow How to Ask.

Comment: Oups sorry sorry

Comment: Edit your post to include the code in text as code blocks

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002706/ban-dm-message-on-discord-js?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before kicking the member, you can do `member.send`:

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first() //faster than message.guild.member(user)
member.send('Any message');
```